# Biblatex: Print shorttitle for authors cited with multiple works in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, multiple-citations

Is it possible to print shorttitle field at the end of the items in bibliography only for the works from authors cited with multiple works in the document? For authors cited with one work, there will be no shorttitle info in the bibliography. The preamble is as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authortitle-terse,bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can hook into the `finentry` bibmacro to print text at the end of the bibliography entry.

A short look at [`authortitle-terse.cbx` (ll. 11-15 in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle-terse.cbx#L11-L15) shows that the citation style uses `\ifsingletitle` to decide whether or not to print the title in citations, so we do the same here.

We top things off by slightly modifying the output of the `citedas` bibstring to make it more appropriate here.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-terse]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  citedas = {cited as},
}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\bibstring{citedas}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
  \finentry
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
ipsum \autocite{knuth:ct:a}
dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E. Computers & Typesetting. Vol. A: The T E Xbook. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1984. Cited as TeXbook. — Computers & Typesetting. Vol. B: T E X: The Program. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1986. Cited as TeX. Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. Worman, Nancy. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.